# How can I bypass available memory check?

Tags: windows-7, memory, bypass

How can I bypass memory(RAM) check on windows 7 ?
I have an application who refuses to run because I have less than the required 2GB of ram how can I trick it to run anyway ?

EDIT: to clarify the application runs fine on another computer and uses around 700 Mb.
What's blocking me is the setup process who refuses to install because it detects I have 1GB

Comment: Move the HDD to an identical computer with 2GB RAM, install it there, and put the drive back.  For that matter, you could borrow 1GB RAM to set it up on your computer.  Have you thought about why they require 2GB (it may not all be for the program, itself)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I succeeded in installing the software by disabling WMI 
http://computerstepbystep.com/windows_management_instrumentation_service.html

WMI was used to check my RAM config.

So in the end it was possible :D

To disable Windows Management Instrumentation(WMI) just disable the service with the same name by running msconfig and uncheck it in the services tab

Comment: Congrats.  Consider expanding your answer with the essential steps from the link to avoid your answer losing value when the link rots.

Answer (score -1):

Buy more RAM.

Seriously, it probably checks because it needs 2 GB of RAM.
I do not know of any method spoofing RAM in Windows (nor Linux).
One thing you *could try* is [resize the amount of Virtual Memory](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/36092/windows-7-and-8-change-the-size-of-virtual-memory/).

Comment: buying ram is not an option